# Strange Padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues with some strange padding on the right side of this website I'm working on right now. I'm currently viewing it on a 13" Macbook Pro, full-screen within that viewport. (It has a lot of issues on the smaller viewports that I'm aware of; I haven't gotten to that point in the process.) I've inspected it thoroughly with the developer tools in Chrome but haven't been able to find anything to account for the padding-right or margin-right that's creating the horizontal scroll.

It's currently built with Bootstrap and Flexslider.

Link to repo: https://github.com/helenvholmes/designshow

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal scrollbar also appears on Chrome 25 on my Win 8 64 system, regardless of width.

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the rules for `div.flexslider`.

That removed the horizontal scrollbar for me and *appeared* to leave everything else intact. However, please be warned that I haven't tested all the content thoroughly, so look carefully to see if that rule has other unwanted side effects.

How does that work for you?

Comment: That appeared to work! I will need to test it out on a bunch of other computers but so far, so good. Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure! Hope the fix holds up through your tests. Not every problem can be solved with the addition of a single CSS rule! By the way, cool design.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm glad you like it! If you're in the DC area you should come out for the event.